# Using MS Access database as a file format for desktop application needing open / save type functionality

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns, ms-access, application-design

This is probably a pretty novice design question.  I'm trying to work my way through a number of requirements and give the users the experience they're looking for...

I've written a tool that does big calcluation-type things.  It currently consists of a class library and command line tool (separate .NET projects.) We're using an Access database format as the file type because it can keep all the various tables together in one file.  A few other items about the application:
- There are not many users.  There are no concerns with scalability.
- There are not great concerns with updates.
- Desktop is desired.  Not web.
- Using VB and .NET 3.5 SP1

I now need to develop a GUI front end that will allow typical File/Open and File/Save type operations.

Users expect that they can open a file, edit it some, then either choose to save it or close it unsaved -- without *any* changes being written back to the file.  Saving it would obviously save all changes affecting all tables back to the file.

Does it then make sense to use a temp file for something like a proxy then? To, when a user "opens" a file, copy the source Access file to a local temp file and then use that for the editing session? Then, if the user "saves", copy the local temp file back to the source path?

Is that question clear? Is the design horrid??? Any comments or suggestions?

**Update:** [tagged with ms-access tag too] Also, I omitted the fact that users would expect typical File / Save As functionality too.  I think the design I've put in question in this post is what is traditionally called the Proxy design pattern.  Has anyone tried this (successfully!) with Access database files before? Words of caution or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that approach would work, but it's not the greatest design in the world.
What you're talking about is transactions, basically. A transaction is a set of operations to a database that are atomic, either they ALL go in or none of them do.

Usually, you bracket a transaction with a BEGIN and a COMMIT. That way the transaction doesn't involve the entire database, only the specific parts you're working on right then.

Hard to tell from your description though. In your case, maybe all or nothing would be ok, and the "access file copy technique" you describe would work fine.

But if the user expects to open the DB, make a few changes over here, commit them, then make a few changes over there and then undo those, it won't work well for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is a good thought - use of transactions.  

I didn't put in my original post that I need to support the typical "Save As" functionality too.  I'm not sure this is possible going the transaction route.  If I started the transaction, the user made edits, and then tried to do a Save As, then I'd want to leave the original file as is but somehow commit the transactions to the new "Saved As" file.  Sorry for leaving this detail out of the original post.

You agree that the transactions wouldn't work so well with that, right?

Comment: Yeah, in that case, no, transactions probably would work so great. Out of curiousity, why an access file in that case? Why not just create your data model from persistable objects and persist them all to XML files on demand. They you get nice readable XML, you get all the Save and save as functionality, and no reliance on Access. Unless the datasets are just HUGE, that might be the better alternative.

Comment: Well, calculations that result from the system (and stored back to the input file) can be huge in number -- 1000's of rows of data.

Hmm... I like text.  I hadn't considered XML or persisting the objects directly.  That's on the perimeter of my .NET knowledge.  

I think my users prefer Access because they can use it to tweak numbers outside the front end if need be.  I guess the same can be said for XML, but even Access intimidates some users! I think editing/tweaking XML might totally scare people off.  Still, I will run this by them.  Thank you again for your comments/suggestions.

Comment: Well, thousands shouldn't be a problem with XML. If it's going to go to hundreds of thousands, that might be more of an issue. Dpending on the format of the data, you could write out to a more proprietary format than XML (say some binary format) and then give users an IMPORT/EXPORT functionality to from Access or Excel. Just a few more things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The design isn't pretty I guess, but if you are using an MS Access database as a sort of "scenario" file for your calculations then this approach is the easiest to achieve what you want.

As @drventure mentioned, normally you would use transactions to control whether changes get saved or not, but in your app you would have to start a "gobal" transaction upon opening the access database and committing or abandoning that transaction depending on what the user does. I have no idea however, how Access performs handling a transaction with multiple changes on multiple tables that is "open" for a long time...

In both approaches you would have to deal with saves without closing the app? In the case of the transaction approach that is fairly simple: commit the global transaction and and immediately starting a new one. In the temporary file approach this could be a little more involved, as it would require closing and reopening the temporary file and making sure that the state of the application is preserved or re-established.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much much the idea.  The Access database is kind of a "scenario file" like you say.  And the users are expecting the sort of traditional MDI approach that they're familiar with with the MS Office apps.  Each document in the MDI will probably show something like a treeview and grid in it for that particular document/file.

Comment: If each file is opened by only one user, I don't know that it would be too much of a problem to do everything in a single transaction. However, my question is whether it's all or nothing -- that is, will all transactions be committed if any of them are, and otherwise none at all, or is it some to be committed and some not? I expect it's more likely to be the latter, which would put less of a strain on your temp file space (which is where transactions are stored), since the transactions would be in smaller chunks.